# SpringApplicationConfiguration can't be resolved to a type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pom.xml

I know this question has been posted before, but I couldn't resolve it from that post. I get the error that "SpringApplicationConfiguration cannot be resolved to a type" in the following code:

```
package com.caveofprogramming.tests;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringBootConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;

import com.caveofprogramming.App;


@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(App.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
public class StatusTest {

@Test
public void testDummy() {
    long value = 7l;

    assertNotNull("Value should not be null", value);
}
}
```

This has the following dependency in the pom.xml file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9.RELEASE</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    </dependency>
```

What can I do to get rid of this error but not cause any other issues? Thanks.

Here below is App.java: 
    package com.caveofprogramming;

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView;

@SpringBootApplication
public class App extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder 
application) {
    return application.sources(App.class);
}

@Bean
public TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();

String[] defs = {"/WEB-INF/tiles.xml"};

tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(defs);

return tilesConfigurer;
}

@Bean
public UrlBasedViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
    UrlBasedViewResolver tilesViewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
    tilesViewResolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
    return tilesViewResolver;
}

}
```

Comment: You may want to include what App.java looks like, that's what it's barking about.  On a bigger note, you shouldn't be using SpringApplicationConfiguration, it's long since been deprecated.  Try running with SpringRunner.class and drop the SpringApplicationConfiguration`

Comment: Below I've included App.java. I need to determine what to replace the SpringApplicationConfiguration annotation with. I tried SpringRunner.class with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a configuration like this will get you going

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.caveofprogramming"})
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```

I assume there's a lot more to your test (or there intends to be) than what you've listed.  If you're truly going to just make a simple test like this, run with the Mockito runner, and you don't need the rest of that nonsense.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

Note that this assumes you're attempting to perform a test of your controllers, based on the fact that you have annotated your test with `@WebAppConfiguration`